# After Upgrading to Angular 7, fonts are not available in assets folder

Tags: angular, angular7

After Upgrading to Angular 7 I don't get the fonts any more

I had the font fonts folder in **src/assets/fonts/roboto**

[image]

And I have referred the fonts in my global style **styles.scss**,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
  src: url('/src/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/src/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Now after the upgrade I am not having that file copied to the assets folder.

[image]

And my angular.json goes this way, pretty much default

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyUI": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "targets": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/MyUI",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyUI:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyUI:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyUI:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MyUI-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "MyUI:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "MyUI:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyUI",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

So do I needs to specifically mention my fonts? or do I have to move it out of the assets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I should update my path to.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto-Regular";
  src: url('../src/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../src/assets/fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be /assets/fonts/.... since that's where they are being copied to?

Comment: @DovezHefetz - That's correct, relative from styles.scss location.

Answer (score 1):

The `assets` option of the builder by default will copy everything listed to a folder named `assets` relative to the app base path, therefore you need to change your path from `/src/assets/fonts/roboto` to `assets/fonts/roboto/...`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that helped me was to change the url path to the relative path of the font folder. From this:

```
  src: url("/assets/fonts/main/Assistant-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
```

to

```
  src: url("../../fonts/main/Assistant-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
```

And this happend after updating from angular 2 to angular 12...